# Comparing character dates across columns in R

Tags: r

I have 3 desired "variables" (dates) I want to compare across my dataset. 
My first variable is in two columns, one with "%Y-%M-%D" and the second column with "%h:%m" format.
My second variable is in two columns, one with: "%Y-%M-%D" and the second column with "%h:%m" format.
My third variable is in the format of: "%Y-%M-%D %h:%m:%s" (one column).

Unfortunately all of these columns are characters. I've tried combining the columns for desired vars 2 and 3 with lubridate to be similar to my third variable:
`df$new1<-with(df, ymd(old_date)+ hms(old_time))`, 
`df$new2<-with(df, ymd(old_date)+ hms(old_time))`
then converting my three variables to POSIXct. After this, I want to flag observations where the date in variable 3 is greater than the dates in variables 1 and 2, 
I've used: `df1 <- mutate(df, flag = ifelse(var3>=new2 & var3>=new1, 1, 0) )`
but I have been very unsuccessful (raw dates where var3 is clearly lower than var2 are being flagged etc.). I think my problem is in vars 1 and 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are all character columns,  we can use `paste` to concatenate the columns and with `anytime` convert the columns to DateTime class

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(anytime)
df1 %>%
   mutate(new1 = anytime(str_c(old_date1, old_time1, sep= ' ')),
          new2 = anytime(str_c(old_date2, old_time2, sep= ' ')),
          new3 = anytime(str_c(old_date3, old_time3, sep=' ')),
          flag = as.integer(new3 > new2 & new3 > new1))
```

Comment: Thanks! Needed to install RApiDatetime but it worked.